# Are there any differences between the first episode of The Man in the High Castle released in January 2015 and the one released in October 2015?

Tags: the-man-in-the-high-castle

The pilot episode of Amazon's [The Man in the High Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_in_the_High_Castle_(TV_series)) was originally [released on 15 January 2015](http://deadline.com/2015/01/mad-dogs-man-in-the-high-castle-point-of-honor-cocked-amazon-studios-first-pilot-season-2015-1201342046/) on their Prime web video streaming service as part of the company’s first pilot season of 2015.

Due to its success, Amazon [announced on February 18 2015](http://deadline.com/2015/02/amazon-orders-original-series-man-in-the-high-castle-mad-dogs-video-1201375797/) that a full season would be produced. This full season was released on 20 November 2015, with the first two episodes being available [during a preview weekend](http://deadline.com/2015/10/man-in-the-high-castle-amazon-1201589863/) starting 23 October 2015.

> The pilot and episode 2 will be available for no-charge at
>   http://www.amazon.com/maninthehighcastle beginning at 12 AM PST on
>   Friday, October 23rd and ending at 11:59 PM PST on Sunday, October
>   25th in the U.S. and UK. Following the Preview Weekend, the show’s
>   second episode will available exclusively to all Amazon Prime Members,
>   prior to the season launch of all episodes on November 20th.

Are there any differences between the pilot episode released in January versus the one that is part of the full season?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just compared both versions and there are no differences between them.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote on this. I've also seen both and couldn't spot any difference. Of course I didn't watch them back to back, so I also might have missed something.

Comment: Found a backup copy of the preview version and compared them. No differences were found.

Answer (score 3):

I saw the original version of the pilot at Comic-Con in 2015. There are least a couple differences between that version and what I saw on Amazon. One difference is that Joe kills the cop who stopped him and helped him change the tire. In the version on Amazon, Joe does not kill him. I cannot recall the other change but I believe they both make Joe look less ruthless.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a version of episode 1 on Dailymotion that had actor Rick Turner playing Julianna Crain's step father.  He was listed in credits as "Arnold Crain" (not Walker).  The actor was not in the version aired later.  Daniel Roebuck was in the later version. Same script lines.  Different camera angles too.